# AWK LINUX Find regular files that have more than 2 extensions

Tags: linux, awk

I want to print path to files that have more than 2 extensions using AWK command on Linux.

I want for example print paths to files like file.ext1.ext1 (files that have repeated extensions)

Sorry for misleading comment, that was to another problem, I deleted that.

Comment: Hi Piodo! Please can you add some more information to your post. It would really help to see some example input and the desired output as well as any attempts (even if they don't really work) you have made to solve this issue...

Comment: As It currently stands, your "question" just looks like you are asking other people to do your work for you. By providing some code that shows you at least attempted a solution, it'll help the community to guide you towards the answer instead of just handing it to you.

Comment: @Piodo, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36332550/edit) your question, and update with actual goal. As it is currently written, your question is different from above [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332550/awk-linux-find-regular-files-that-have-more-than-2-extensions/36332991#comment60287722_36332550)

Comment: why does it have to use **awk**?

Comment: because `awk` is awksome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

this checks whether any of the extensions are identical.
e.g. file.x.y.z.x

```
$ find . -type f | 
  awk -F'/' '{n=split($NF,a,"."); 
              for(i=1;i<n;i++) 
                   for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++) 
                       if(a[i]==a[j]) {print; next}}'
```

perhaps your question is finding files with more than one extension?  If so, much easier

```
$ find . -type f | awk -F'/' 'split($NF,a,".")>2'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Comparing last two extensions:

```
for i in `find . -type f`; do echo $i|awk -F. '{if$((NF-1)==$NF){print}}'; done
```

**sample result**

```
./temp/Release_V1.0.2.backup.zip.zip
./temp/file1.2.txt.txt
```

#### Matching consecutive similar extensions

```
for i in `find . -type f`; do echo $i|awk -F. '{for (j=NF;j>0;j--){if($j==$(j-1)){print ; break}}}'; done
```

**sample result**

```
./temp/file1.2.txt.txt.zip
./temp/Release_V1.0.2.backup.zip.zip
./temp/file1.2.txt.txt
```

Comment: It only compares the last 2 extensions. I wanto to find even files like that : file.ext1.ext2.ext1

Comment: @Piodo, I went by your example. It has only two extensions.

Comment: @Piodo, updated my answer to suite consecutive extension match.

Answer (score -2):

ok , but what i anderstand from your question, you can use this code

```
ls|awk 'FS="." {if($3==".")print $1 "." $}'
```

Comment: Don't parse `ls`. The Awk script has several syntax errors, and could be much simpler.